new Date() validation of string with number
When inputing string with number the new Date() is missbehaving, is there another way how to achieve this without regex?
let string = 'some string 1';
let invalid = new Date(string);

it is still parsing as a Date value
Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

I'm expecting it as an invalid date
Update
let string = 'some string 1';
let invalid = new Date(string.replace(/\s/g, ''));

Seem to resolve to Invalid Date as i want to and it seem to proper validate all dates also human readable dates like Sun, 1 Dec 2024 is handled correctly returning that it is a date indeed.
but still it have missbehaviour when entering
let string = 'some string, 0';
let invalid = new Date(string.replace(/\s/g, ''));

console.log(invalid)

Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)


FWIW this is implementation specific.  Internally this will be using Date.parse which only technically supports one format - anything else is up to the implementation to decide how to handle.  In chrome at least, it appears to do as you've described.  In Firefox, it returns an invalid date.

On possible solution: Check if date is 01/01/2001 00:00:00 then claim it's not valid.  This may not be viable, depending on what you need the date for.   If it's "enter a date in the last 20 years" then it's ok to check for this.

@JamesThorpe - in my Firefox it returns a Jan 1 2001 date

IMHO, attempting to accept everything but blatantly invalid input is a no-go, no matter how terribly popular the approach is. The mere existence of ambiguous formats (is 10/12/2024 American October or European December?) should discourage so. Require users to provide a fixed specific format and reject everything that doesn't match.

@JaromandaX nice... it's not my day-to-day browser, so probably needs an update.  just goes to show that it's not even consistent within a single implementation though!

this is one time libraries can help - don't re-invent the wheel - research javascript date libraries and find one that is suitable to your requirements

If you don't mind using javascript library and the date string input is in fixed format, try Moment.js
var string = 'some string 1';
var validDate = moment(string, 'ddd, D MMM YYYY');
console.log(validDate.isValid()); // return false

var string = 'Sun, 1 Dec 2024';
var validDate = moment(string, 'ddd, D MMM YYYY');
console.log(validDate.isValid()); // return true


So the moment library is i believe deprecated that is why i do not want to use it

@Dzi Then, you may need to learn Luxon. It has similar function with momentjs. But, I don't use it yet so I can't give you code example.

Depending on the Data that gets passed, it could be quite simple to check if date is valid. You can use isNaN for this.


let string = 'some string 1';
let invalid = !isNaN(new Date(string));

if (invalid) {
  console.log("Not a Valid string");
} else {
  console.log("Date is valid");
}



This will return true if the string is "kind of" valid. e.g abc 1. In this case the date function assumes that this could be a day or so. Than he would expect 1 is the month. abc 13 would end up in not valid because there is no month 13. So you should consider what data you really get, not what theoreticle possible.
You could build larger validations or might go for some online libs
similar to moment.js (deprecated).

i had tis check there and it is still
return (date !== 'Invalid Date') && !isNaN(date);
but maybe the problem is and?

Actually new Date('foobar') returns Invalid Date as string. Obvirously you have a problem with your check there, yes. You dont need to check both.

new Date('foobar 1'); was returning a date for me it is checking for both but i double cheked that is not causing the issue, try to run you snippet with new Date('foobar , 1') it was not about the string but string with number also i need human readable dates

It actually thinks that 1 is jan, you can switch the number up to 12, after that it is invalid again. What are the actuall contents that you may could pass? i mean in what case could it be an invalid string that gets passed into the date function ?

you may could go with moment.js and use the isValidmethod. Perhaps...

in your answer you mention moment.js which is deprecated and no longer monitored i don't think i want to use deprecated libraries that is why in first place im trying to do it with new Date and i dont think we want to use more libraies in the project i know there is posibility with regex but that will be the last resort

this was just a sample, you could go for similar libs.

@Dzi What is you expected input? i mean you could type in all type of crap, but what is the actuall what you expect?

so outcome what i expect valid dates as a dates but with invalid dates like fooo,  1 or any invaid string with number to be invalid new Date() seem to try to parse everything with a number to a valid date

I mean a airplane could land on a car, but I still would not expect that one does. If you know what i mean. I would only prevent things that can happen, not the one that are possible.

well in my case it is possible as i have ValueParses which is parsing value to specific category -> date, number, or value itself that is why it was original question

Since you have parses, can't you determin if the parse should be a form of date/time construct ore something else?
